# p5.js canvas adds unwanted scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, scrollbar, p5.js

I am creating a simple p5.js canvas using the values from it's parent like this:

```js
// Canvas properties
var $musicscape = $("#musicscape");

// p5.js functions
function setup() {
    var canvas = createCanvas(
        $musicscape.outerWidth(),
        $musicscape.outerHeight()) ;
    canvas.id("canvas")
    canvas.parent($musicscape[0]);
}
```

My `musicscape` element has the following sass properties and takes on the right size without creating any scrollbars.

```
#musicscape
    position: absolute
    right: 0
    top: 0
    width: 50vw
    height: 100vh
```

Here is [a jsfiddle which shows the error](https://jsfiddle.net/5y9qhmos/1/).

However, when I add the canvas which has the exact size as my `html`, `body` and `#musicscape` elements, a vertical scrollbar is added. The only way to remove it is to set the canvas width to `$musicscape.outerHeight() - 3` which also creates a small white line at the bottom that isn't part of the canvas. **How can I get rid of the vertical scrollbar while keeping the canvas to the size of its parent?** I checked and there are no padding or margin anywhere on my page.

I am testing on Chrome btw.

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] that we can run ourselves?

Comment: @KevinWorkman I added a jsFiddle to my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML canvas element is by default an inline element ([list of inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements#Elements)).
So even if you set it's height exactly same as it's parent it overflows because of line-spacing. To prevent it set canvas to a block level element in your SASS file.

```
#canvas
    display: block;
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS Flexible Box Layout Module
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="noscrollbars.css">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <script src="p5.js"></script>
      <script src="myscript.js"></script>
    </head>  <body>  <main> </main> </body>
</html>
```

noscrollbars.css

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
    body {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
        
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```